# How do I obtain statistics about sent email from Mail.app?

Tags: osx-lion, script, apple-mail, sent-items

I use the Mail.app in OS X Lion.  I would like to determine statistics about all emails sent within a timeframe (in this case, from 2010 to current).  In particular, I'd like histograms for emails per day, week, month, year, most frequent hour, etc.
I am interested in pre-packaged programs, if they exist, or in scripted solutions if necessary.

Comment: heh heh, ask Apple or the NSA, they probably know more about your email habits than you do.

Comment: Do you have all your mails still stored in folders (Sent Mail or similar)?

Comment: yes, all of them are on the sent folder

Comment: obvious question is how to extract dates and such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mailsum](http://mailsum.com/) seems perfect for you (screenshot from site included below). It's $2 on the App Store.

[image: Mailsum Screenshot]

Comment: This product doesn't seem to be available anymore - i'm looking for such a solution, if anyone finds something please update this answer!